# How to fix incorrect display of the nested grouping symbol in the "details" tag?

Tags: html, css, hierarchy

If the top level is expanded, then all nested levels are assigned the "-" symbol, even if they are collapsed:
[jsfiddle.net/acces969/4eh6puvk/1/](https://jsfiddle.net/acces969/4eh6puvk/1/)

```
<div class="treeHTML">Root
  <div>level 1
    <details><summary></summary>
      <div >level 2
        <details><summary></summary>
          <div >
            level 3
          </div>
        </details>
      </div>
    </details>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your CSS selector for the open details is slightly off:

```css
.treeHTML details[open] summary:before {/* styles */}
```

This will select all `summary` elements which are children of an open details element, (including non-direct children)

To only select only the direct child of the open details, you should use the [`>`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/c/child/) selector:

```css
.treeHTML details[open] > summary:before {/* styles */}
```

Comment: Wow. Thank you very much, you helped a lot. And the problem is solved and I now know what this selector does (I've seen it a lot before)